# Reading all but last few lines of a data file

Tags: visual-c++

I can easily skip the header of a data file using getline, but then when I parse through the data file and get to the footer of the file, I end up stuck in a loop because the program is trying to parse columns of data that no longer exist. Is there an easy way to stop reading when there is no longer data in the line? It looks like there is a blank line followed by some footer information, but I cannot guarantee that all of my data files will look like that (i.e. I need something pretty generic).

Comment: What have you got (code wise) so far? Can you post a simple example of the contents of the file you're trying to parse? Would checking if the line ends in \r\n (or whatever your environment's newline character is) help?

Comment: `while (q < 16)
{
     while (liness >> temp)
     {
          if (q == 0)
          {
               ...
          }
          ...
          q++;
     }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your existing code (edit your question and put it there, not in a comment), I see you have nested loops.  But what you really want is one loop with two reasons to exit.

```
while ((q < 16) && (liness >> temp)) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the line into a string, parse if only if you see `\n` at the end.

Comment: Wouldn't "/n" show up on a line regardless of what was on the line? I'm running through multiple columns of data, and when I no longer have columns, my program gets stuck because it is still looking for the columns.